# How to config typeregistryconfigurer in cucumber 7

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-java

I want to have automatic configuration for types in cucumber 7 , do you know how can I config `typeregistryconfigurer` in cucumber 7 ?

Comment: You don't have to any more. You can use annotations https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-java#transformers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `typeregistryconfigurer` , we need to use provided annotations in cucumber 7 like  `@DataTableType`